# Selecting data for 1 specific user from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

So my database is composed of 5 tables with different columns for each one. The only column that keeps them all identified is the `id`. I'm trying to get the data for a specific user, but I only seem to get all users of the database instead.

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT
    ControlAccess.UserName,
    ControlAccess.Pass,
    Users.First_Name,
    Users.Last_Name, 
    UserInfo.Age, 
    UserInfo.Country,
    UserInfo.Address,
    UserInfo.ZipCode,
    Sessions.Matrix1,
    Sessions.Matrix2,
    Sessions.Result,
    Operations.Operation,
    FilePath.LocationFiles
FROM 
    MatrixUsers.UserInfo
INNER JOIN 
    MatrixUsers.Users
ON 
    UserInfo.idUserInfo = Users.idUsers = 1
INNER JOIN 
    MatrixUsers.ControlAccess
ON 
    ControlAccess.idControlAccess = UserInfo.idUserInfo = 1
INNER JOIN 
    MatrixUsers.Sessions
ON 
    Sessions.idSessions = ControlAccess.idControlAccess = 1
INNER JOIN 
    MatrixUsers.FilePath
ON 
    FilePath.idFilePath = Sessions.idSessions = 1
INNER JOIN 
    MatrixUsers.Operations
ON 
    Operations.idOperations = FilePath.idFilePath = 1;
```

I tried putting **1** at the end of each `id` to see if they matched, but I still get all the users.

I'm new to SQL and I'm only familiar with matching rows, but not choosing specific one.

Here are the columns of each table:

```
ControlAccess: {idControlAccess, UserName, Pass}
Sessions: {idSessions, Matrix1, Matrix2, Result}
FilePath: {idFilePath, LocationFiles}
Operations: {idOperation, Operation}
UserInfo: {idUserInfo, Age, Country, Address, ZipCode, Phone}
```

Comment: I recommend you to read some basics of SQL first, because it's hard to help here. Your query is all wrong, simply. ALL wrong.

Comment: Well I know is wrong of course. If I remove the "=1" I get the display of ALL existing data in the Database. Im trying to get the data from ONE specific user for example the one who's ID = 1 in all tables.

Comment: You need to add `WHERE` clause, but it's still hard to understand what your joins should be like. You join your tables in weird way. Do they all share reference to the `UserInfo` table? I think it would be best if you shared the full structure of your tables.

Comment: Thing is that my assignment is a matrix calculator where the matrices and results are stored in 3 different files. So each user does a matrix calculation and save the files. Then the Database consist of 5 tables where UserInfo has personal data, ControlAccess has username and password, Operation has the method used  (sum, substract etc) Session has the name of the matrix files and FilePath contains the path to the files. They all have reference in their id, where for example the user who's id is 1 is the same on all tables. So that all info info on each row of each table match each other.

Comment: Please provide the full list of columns of each table you want to use here, because - as you said - you have poor understanding of SQL and it's hard to predict what you mean.

Comment: What is the common field for all those tables? Primary keys are the same? Your table structure doesn't make any sense :(

Comment: The primary key is the same for all. Like each id is suppose to link each table. :( Do you understand? Im so so sorry I can't be more accurate.

Comment: So your relations are 1:1 and they should all be in one table perhaps. But still, I feel that you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Its alright! Got it to work now, thanks for your time! Perhaps you can explain how does the Foreign key works and the primary key?

Comment: Perhaps you can google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just user where after all the joins

```
WHERE ANY_COLUMN_REFER_TO_USER_ID  = YOUR_NEEDED_ID
```

so your full query would be like :

```
SELECT
    ControlAccess.UserName,
     ControlAccess.Pass,
     Users.First_Name,
    Users.Last_Name, 
    UserInfo.Age, 
     UserInfo.Country,
     UserInfo.Address,
     UserInfo.ZipCode,
    Sessions.Matrix1,
    Sessions.Matrix2,
    Sessions.Result,
    Operations.Operation,
     FilePath.LocationFiles
   FROM MatrixUsers.UserInfo
    INNER JOIN MatrixUsers.Users
    ON UserInfo.idUserInfo = Users.idUsers
    INNER JOIN MatrixUsers.ControlAccess
    ON ControlAccess.idControlAccess = UserInfo.idUserInfo
    INNER JOIN MatrixUsers.Sessions
    ON Sessions.idSessions = ControlAccess.idControlAccess
    INNER JOIN MatrixUsers.FilePath
    ON FilePath.idFilePath = Sessions.idSessions
    INNER JOIN MatrixUsers.Operations
    ON Operations.idOperations = FilePath.idFilePath
    WHERE UserInfo.idUserInfo = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use WHERE when you want specific user. for example, select user_id from table where user_id=the_specific_user_id . Follow this basic to built you complicate statement.